# Applescript - to do script with administrator privileges with display dialog

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript, sudo

Is there a way to write a "to do script" with administrator privileges like you can with a "do shell script" ?  I have a script that I am writing that opens a terminal window and gets the size of another user account but I get permission denied errors. I can easily solve this by entering sudo before the command but I don't want to enter a password in the terminal window. I want to be prompted with a dialog so I can enter a password just like I would get if I used a "do shell script"

This is part of my script that I have:

tell application "Terminal"

activate
    do script "sudo du -sh /Users/example"

end tell

I know that you can solve this also like this:

do shell script "du -sh /Users/example" with administrator privileges

but doing it like this opens a terminal window but does not start the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without involving Terminal.app at all

```
set userSize to do shell script "du -sh /Users/example | awk '{print $1}'" with administrator privileges
```

The `awk` command strips the size part from the result.

Comment: the dialog is great thanks. I need the terminal window  to output the result though. My goal is to monitor a folders size in a while loop. Like this: 
while :; do clear; du -sh /Users/example ; sleep 2; done" 

So I need the terminal to open a window and have that run. Is that possible with administrator privileges? Again I don't want to input the password in the terminal window so I want to avoid typing sudo before the du command.

Comment: You can also do that control flow in AppleScript without Terminal.app. Once you have entered the admin password you got a time interval of 5 minutes where the access is granted.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is correct, but it should not be used with a tell "Terminal" block at all.

With the script bellow (only the 2 lines), Terminal will not be open and the only window will be the one asking your admin password.

```
set UserSize to do shell script "du -sh /Users/test" with administrator privileges
display dialog UserSize
```